# $_SERVER['document_root']?

Tags: php, superglobals

is this pointing to the directory where the current file is executed?

Comment: 'document_root' is NOT the same as "DOCUMENT_ROOT".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it points to the root of your webserver - the topmost folder of your website.

If you want the directory of the current file, use:

`dirname(__FILE__);`

Comment: +1: This is the correct way to do it. (I realize I posted this twice, but the two answers mentioning this solution were literally posted 1 second apart... 49 and 50 seconds before I loaded this page)

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
>   The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, depending on how the server is set up. A much better method is:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__); // return the absolute file-path to where the current PHP file is
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not,

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` points to the root directory of your webserver, while `PATH_INFO` points to the directory where the current file is executed.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. If I have a address http://myhost/my/path/xyz.php/foo/bar, then PATH_INFO contains foo/bar.

Comment: Oops, took too much time editing :) 
DOCUMENT_ROOT is a pysical server path, but PATH_INFO is a pseudo-path that is appended to the name of the php script, like this:
http://myhost/my/path/xyz.php/foo/bar.
foo/bar will usually be an internal route in your logic. Your PHP is free to interpret it as a server path, but that's not mandatory.
The browser, on the other hand, knows nothing about that and thinks that my/path/xyz.php/foo/bar is the "current object", and when you refer to a CSS oder image by "./sna.foo" then you'll be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
>   The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: you're contradicting yourself

Answer (score 0):

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

as the name implies it's a root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. It's a path relative to the root of your server (not your document root) that describes the directory of the current script. It does not have a trailing slash.