# Php: DIR and DOCUMENT_ROOT returning different paths

Tags: php

I'm using a new server host and `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is not working because returns a different path than the real one.

Example, I added `includes/inc.php` to the `public_html` folder on the server and used this code:

```
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'inc.php');
```

This is the result:

```
Warning: include_once(/var/www/html/includes/inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tom_server/public_html/index.php on line 4
```

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is returning something unexpected. If I use `dirname(__FILE__)` it returns the right path:

```
/home/tom_server/public_html/includes/inc.php
```

But `dirname(__FILE__)` is not a useful solution as I need main root folder for relative paths. Is this a server configuration issue?

Comment: `PHP` is going to get your document root from the web server ..  IE `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"` inside of your vHosts or config file ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_SERVER\['document\_root'\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072126/serverdocument-root)

Answer (score 1):

`/home/<username>/public_html` is the default [user's web content directory used by apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/public_html.html) if this feature is enabled.

When activated, the usual intended use of such personal directories is to store some static pages (cv, personal page in the company/institution...) and small dev/tests for easy access without having to configure anything. I used them a lot for students when I worked in a university a very long while ago so they could store and share their assignments.

When this feature is enabled, the pages in personal directories are served by the default webserver/virtual host, for which the document root is configured to `/var/www/html` by default on most linux distributions.

If you want to have a document root starting at the root of your php application, you can:

- Fast and easy but ugly: move your application files to `/var/www/html`
- Single user/app solution: modify the default webserver to point to your app (in place or in a new folder).
- Prefered: use a dedicated folder for your app and configure a new [Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/examples.html) in apache

If you do not have access to your server configuration and can only publish your files in your current user web directory, well... I have a bad news: you will not be able to use `DOCUMENT_ROOT` anymore in this context.

Details for configuring apache are beyond the scope of your question and probably belong to an other stackexchange site.